# C# парсер: как понять, какие порты используются для подключения?

Tags: c#, anglesharp

Пишу маленькую программу-пример для парсинга заголовка статей с Хабра (по факту, копирую, разбираясь, что и как работает) с помощью AngleSharp в VS2017. При запуске непосредственно парсинга ничего не происходит, хотя проверка показывает, что работа происходит (в частности, заканчивается цикл обработки). 
Вот класс ParserWorker, который и обрабатывает полученную информацию:

```
class ParserWorker<T> where T : class
{   //поле с обобщенным типом IParser
    IParser<T> parser;
    //поле, в котором хранятся настройки для парсера
    IParserSettings parserSettings;

    HtmlLoader loader;

    bool isActive;

    private HabraParser habraParser;
    private HabraSettings habraSettings;

    // пара публичных свойств для полей parser и parserSettings
    #region Properties
    public IParser<T> Parser
    {
        get
        {
            return parser;
        }
        set
        {
            parser = value;
        }

    }

    public IParserSettings Settings
    {
        get
        {
            return parserSettings;
        }
        set
        {
            parserSettings = value;
            //создаем  новый экземпляр с новыми настройками парсера
            loader = new HtmlLoader(value);
        }


    }
    //свойство, доступное лишь для чтения для контроля работы класса
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get

        {
            return IsActive;
        }
    }
    //#region позволяет указать блок кода, который можно разворачивать и сворачивать  в редакторе кода Visual Studio.
    #endregion
    //пара событий
    //первое событие, возвращающее спарсенные за итерацию данные.В аргументах мы передаем ссылку на парсер, а затем 
    public event Action<object, T> OnNewData;
    //второе событие отвечает за информирование при завершении работы парсера
    public event Action<object> OnCompleted;
    //конструктор, в котором принимается экземпляр, реализующий интерфейс IParser
    public ParserWorker(IParser<T> parser)
    {   //присваиваем значение аргумента полю
        this.parser = parser;
    }
    //конструктор,который кроме парсера принимает его настройки
    public ParserWorker(IParser<T> parser, IParserSettings parserSettings) : this(parser)//чтобы не дублировать код, вызываем первый конструктор и передадим ему парсер
    {//записываем настройки парсера в поле
        this.parserSettings = parserSettings;
    }

    public ParserWorker(HabraParser habraParser, HabraSettings habraSettings)
    {
        this.habraParser = habraParser;
        this.habraSettings = habraSettings;
    }

    //добавляем два метода для запуска и остановки парсера - Start и Abort
    public void Start()
    {//в методе Start вызываем метод Worker (он будет асинхронным)
        isActive = true;
        Worker();
    }

    public void Abort()
    {
        isActive = false;
    }
    //закрытый асинхронный метод Worker, контролирующий процесс парсинга
    private async void Worker()
    {//цикл от стартовой до конечной точки из наших настроек
        for (int i = parserSettings.StartPoint; i <= parserSettings.EndPoint; i++)
        {//делаем проверку на активность. Если был использован метод Abort, то выходим из метода
            if (!isActive)
            {//вызов метода OnCompleted в случае, если работа парсера была остановлена
                OnCompleted?.Invoke(this);
                return;
            }
            //С помощью HtmlLoadera получаем исходный код страницы с индексом из цикла
            var source = await loader.GetSourceByPageId(i);
            //создаем HtmlParser, доступный нам из AngleSharp
            var domParser = new HtmlParser();
            //спарсим асинхронно наш исходный код и получим документ, с которым можно работать
            var document = await domParser.ParseAsync(source);
            //передаем нашему парсеру документ и получаем спарсенные данные в переменную result
            var result = parser.Parse(document);
            //вызов метода OnNewData, в который передается ссылка и результат
            OnNewData?.Invoke(this, result);
        }
        //вызов метода OnCompleted в случае, если работа парсера была закончена
        OnCompleted?.Invoke(this);
        isActive = false;
    }

}
```

Со стороны кода вроде бы все в порядке, и я задумался над вопросом: а где указываются параметры подключения программы aka порт и т.д.? Не в этом ли проблема (потому что я указываю адрес сайта обычной ссылкой, по факту )?

P.S. Если кому-то интересно, можете посмотреть мой "код" с комментариями (только не забудьте подключить AngleSharp):
https://yadi.sk/d/1dxbCSNa3NnMo5

Comment: Вы же сайт парсите? Тогда порт или 80 (http) или 443 (https). Если вам нужна помощь в отладке - приведите минимальный пример для воспроизведения проблемы прямо в теле вопроса. Не заставляйте участников идти куда-то там на яндекс диск, качать и запускать непонятно что.

Comment: Прошу прощения за ЯД. Т.е. библиотека сама ставит порт по умолчанию, как я понимаю?  И должна ли выводиться ошибка, если порт заблокирован?
P.S. Мне кажется, что проблема на самом деле либо в обработке, либо в передаче вывода в ListBox,только понять не могу, где.

Comment: Есил не можете понять, в чем проблема - попробуйте ее локализировать. Замените часть кода заглушкой (например, выбросите парсер и вставьте на его место просто Task.Delay + вывод фиксированной строки. В конце концов, поставьте в коде брекпойнты и посмотрите под отладчиком что происходит - вызываются ли ваши события, и в каком порядке они вызываются.